# axios returns __ob__: Observer... when called from Vuex action under Nuxt

Tags: axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I use Nuxtjs and Vuex to maintain state. I want my store actions to fetch data from api endpoints.
code in my store action looks like this:

```
async loadTodos({ commit }) {
  const data = await this.$axios.$get('todos')
  console.log('todos:', data)
  // commit('set_todos', data)
}
```

in dev console, network tab, i see the data coming back perfectly from the server. 4 records with status 200.
in the console, i get garbage. 4 records, each starting with {**ob**: Observer}.
What am i doing wrong?
the same code, when put in regular page, in asyncData, works perfectly. (means, the syntax is ok)
Any idea or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add complete vuex code(state, mutation, getters) and from where you calling that code also to better understand

Comment: I'm trying not to confuse with irrelevant code. the state for our example is simply todos[].
just an empty array.
the mutation in this case is dead simple, but even this was commented out as you can see in my example, because i have no issue with this. only calling the api is giving me troubles. a great api endpoint to get sample todos is:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

Comment: How was this solved @RonAl? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @adelriosantiago, nothing, that's how it is in vue.js.  vue adds some properties that looks like garbage, but it's fine. you can read about what they are (observers), or just ignore them. it's not a bug.